# Prevent AddString(some process) to combobox MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, combobox

I have code witch adds current working processes to combo box and I want to exclude all processes with name: svchost.exe

```
if (Process32First(hSnap, &proc))
{
    pComboBox->AddString(proc.szExeFile);
    while (Process32Next(hSnap, &proc)){
        if (proc.szExeFile != L"svchost.exe")
            pComboBox->AddString(proc.szExeFile);
    }
}
```

I try that code but its not working at all.

How I can exclude all svchost.exe processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cannot use:

```
 if (proc.szExeFile != L"svchost.exe") {...}
```

Using below instead：

```
  if (0!=wcscmp(proc.szExeFile, L"svchost.exe")) {...}
```

When comparing two literals, you cannot use the binary operator like `=`, which will compare the address of the two literals, apparently they addresses will be different in most cases, in your case, literal `L"svchost.exe"` is stored in some static data section of the program which will not equal to process names stored locally in the stack.